# Error when trying to change an index value in pandas dataframe (IndexError: too many indices for array)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to change an index value in my pandas dataframe with:

```py
return1m.rename(index={'2022-08-30':'1 Month'})
```

but I keep getting an error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

And I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Could someone guide me?

[image]

Comment: IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, you can reproduce the error with: `pd.DataFrame(index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2022'])).rename(index={'':''})`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, You get an error because dtype of `Date` in the index is `datetime` so for renaming you need to pass `datetime` instead of a `string`.

```
from datetime import datetime

string_date_time = '2022-08-30'
_datetime = datetime.strptime(string_date_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
df.rename(index={_datetime:'1 Month'})
```

You can also convert `datetime` in index to `string` and then rename like that you do:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str)
df.rename(index={'2022-08-30':'1 Month'})
```

Comment: Shouldn't `rename` just ignore the labels that don't match? without raising error?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, sorry I can't understand.

Comment: [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) by default has `errors='ignore'`. So why is the error raised? ... Is there something special with the datetime index?

Comment: @VladimirFokow, the error is `IndexError: too many indices for array`, you can check when `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` and `df = df.set_index('Date')` you can get op error. and this error comes from the type of matching, the type of index is `dtype='datetime64[ns]'` and op want to replace with an string and string can not match and replace

Comment: yes, I _**have**_ checked ;) I am interested, why it occurs

Comment: I still cannot understand why this happens with datetime but not with other types. You can explicitly set the type of the index to anything but datetime and don't get this error even when the types don't match.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, Yes, you're right, I check for `float`, `int`, and `str` and don't get any errors, I don't understand why this produces error for DateTime :) *(but i think for datetime this can find match only `%Y` or `%y %m` or `%y %d` or only `%d` or ... then produce error and want exactly match. But for `str` and `int` and `float` can check and with 100% sure say can find match or not, But for datetime can find and it is not sure with specific format. )*

Comment: @l'mahdi thanks for the help I used the first of the 2 options and it worked perfectly.  The  explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the error is caused by the datetime object `2022-08-30` being deceivingly looking like a string `'2022-08-30'`, but is actually `datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 30, 0, 0)`.

You could simply rename the index using `df.index`.

```
df.index = ['1 Month']
print(df)

         BTC-USD
1 Month    -0.12
```

Getting OP's (truncated) dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-08-30'], 'BTC-USD': [-0.12]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')
print(df)

            BTC-USD
Date               
2022-08-30    -0.12
```

Comment: This is going to rename only the first row. There may be many occurrences of '2022-08-30'.

Comment: And, if you are planning to assign names one by one in order, is just easier to do `index=['list', 'of', 'many', 'names']`

Comment: ah very sweet! I'd implement that! thanks @IgnatiusReilly !